# Test the behaviour of concurrent code

Tags: java, multithreading, testing

I have an object which after receiving some message changes state asynchronously (an internal thread changes the state). After the state changed I want to test some behavior.

So basically I need to do something like:

1. Create object
2. Send message to object
3. Wait for state to change
4. Test behavior

However, the state is *private* and not exposed.

Is there an elegant solution to this that does not require exposing the state?

And if not - is it reasonable to require changing the main code just to make it more testable?

Comment: There's probably an elegant way to signal state change through the behavior. It would help if you could elaborate on the behavior you're hoping to test. How many possible behaviors are you expecting? For example, is it just going to be that the object returns 0 before the state change and 1 afterwards?

Comment: The actual behavior being tested doesn't matter. The point is that it can only be tested after the state changed, otherwise the test is meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

if the state is private, it is only accessible within its own class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) meaning that you will not be able to get the state from your newly created object without modifying the class.

 Now, whether it is reasonable to modify the class in order to do some testing is up to several factors:

- How many people working on that code?
- How many people already using a previous version of that code?
- Integrity issues that you would face if you change the state variable to public and add a getter method.
- etc.

So of course I can't tell you if it is reasonable or not without knowing in detail the organization of your software. 

I hope this short answer helps you at least to clarify the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the relevant private fields with Reflection assuming you have the permissions to do so.

```
  Foo bar = new Foo();
  bar.setValue(true);

  Field field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("value");
  field.setAccessible(true);
  Object value = field.get(bar);
```

That will get the value stored in a private variable in the class.

This is pretty ugly and you probably shouldn't do it but if you really need to avoid altering the class you're testing with then it should do the trick.

Comment: I'm well aware there are options for ugly solutions. My question was if there's an *elegant solution*, not an ugly one...

Comment: Without modifying the class you're testing that's the most elegant you're going to get. A test class is one of the few places I'd even suggest doing this. Down vote seems harsh to me given that this is a working answer

Comment: That's what I suspected and why I asked the 2nd part of the question. My original thought was to change the state to protected, inherit from the class, and use the inherited class for testing, but it strikes me as somewhat radical to do that (especially changing the access to the state when it should be private by every measure except for testing sake). But I guess there's no good alternative.